# IndexError: list index out of range while writing to file

Tags: python

I am attempting to record the data after the patients seen a doctor into a .txt file however I encountered a error code: IndexError: list index out of range. Please enlighten me on what I had wrong. Thank you!

```
if random.random() <= 0.25:
    print(f'Serving queue number {QueueNumber[i][2]}')
    seenQueue.append(QueueNumber.pop(i))
    return
```

.
.
.

```
def RecordPatientsSeen(seenQueue):
    outfile = open('seenQ3.txt', 'a')
    for i in range(len(seenQueue)):
        outfile.write(f'{seenQueue[i][0]:8} {seenQueue[i][1]:10} {seenQueue[i][2]:<13}\n')
    print(f'{len(seenQueue)} patient added')   
    seenQueue.clear()
```

This is the outcome i got:

```
Menu
1. Register a Patient
2. Call Next Patient
3. List Patients in Queue
4. Search Patient's Queue Position
5. Record Patient's Seen
0. Exit
Enter Option: 5
2 patient added
```

However, I only manage to record 1 patient when it is supposed to record 2 patients' particulars.Below is the error code I encountered:

```
outfile.write(f'{seenQueue[i][0]:8} {seenQueue[i][1]:10} {seenQueue[i]    [2]:<13}\n')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Does seenQueue[i] have length >=3? Can't see what the problem is if we don't know what is in QueueNumber. But most likely the problem is seenQueue[i][2]. Try doing print(len(seenQueue[i])) in the loop before outfile.write...

Comment: I tried it and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only 1 possibility: Some `seenQueue[i]` has fewer than 3 items, so at least one of the

`seenQueue[i][0]`, `seenQueue[i][1]`, `seenQueue[i][2]`

doesn't exist.